# Svelte: Integrating form validation while making use of a major CSS framework like Bootstrap/Material/SemanticUI?

Tags: forms, svelte

I have recently started with Svelte and started by converting a simple React application to Svelte.

I run across some problems when trying to get form validation in semantic-ui to work for me.

It can be that I am shoehorning this and that a better and cleaner approach would be to use computed properties and a validation library that is decoupled for the UI (like hapi/joi).

What approach do you experienced Svelte developer recommend for handling form validation when making use of a major CSS framework like Bootstrap/Material/SemanticUI? Hook/hack in with the provided validation in the framework or use a hybrid approach and only use the CSS while doing validation via computed properties?

Comment: I used a self made (for the experience) rule based sytem with the Svelte use:action element directive. FI: <input .. use:valid={prop, 'mandatory'}....>